# How does Active Directory mark a password expired?

Tags: active-directory, passwords

Our domain has a max password age of 90 days. If I do not change my password for 90 days, what attribute(s) does Active Directory set on my user account to denote that my password has expired?

Is it `pwdLastSet = 0`?

Does it mark my account as disabled via `userAccountControl`? Or will it just require me to change my password on next login?

Can I manually mark a password as expired for a specific user account?

Answer (score 0):

That's is correct. It sets the `pwdLastSet=0`. You can mark the password expired using `AuthenticablePrincipal.ExpirePasswordNow()` method.

Here's how you can expire password for a single account:

```
public static void ExpirePwdNow(string username)
{
   using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com")
   {
      using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, username))
      {
         if (user != null)
         {
            user.ExpirePasswordNow();
            user.Save();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And here's how it looks in AD.

[image]

Note* you can do the same thing using PowerShell or VB script. I don't believe there's a way of expiring the password through GUI, but I can't be sure.